Airflow Docker - Python in VScode could not get airflow.sensors.local_to_remote
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.sensors.local_to_remote import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv  # for CSV operations


python isn't able to understand the 'airflow.sensors.local_to_remote' and hence could not import FileSensor operator.
But its not showing an error on base class lib airflow and line3,4 as well.Only at line 2 it shows error in pylance.
Environment details:

Windows 11

Airflow on docker

using Remote Container on VScode, that opens in a new instance to work with Docker containers.

Windows Airflow directories mapped to docker directory.

.devcontainer folder also added in Airflow directory, contains two files within:
requirements.txt
devcontainer.json

Python interpreter used is 3.8.18 64 bit at usr/local/bin/python which is same as that in the .devcontainer.json file:


{
    "name": "Airflow",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml"],
    "service": "airflow-webserver",
    "workspaceFolder": "/opt/airflow",
    "extensions": [
      "ms-python.python",
      "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python"
    }
  }

7.Airflow web server home screen shows it is not able to import the DAG.

Initially my .devcontainer.json python path was : /usr/local/bin/python3.
I changed it to /usr/local/bin/python because in Vscode, it didn't had any path as '/usr/local/bin/python3.
Some of the python paths it shows are:

